# Getting phone movement direction irrespective of phone face

Tags: android, accelerometer, motion-detection

Referring to this stackoverflow thread
[Transforming accelerometer's data from device's coordinates to real world coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464847/transforming-accelerometers-data-from-devices-coordinates-to-real-world-coordi)

I had similar scope of problem but it differs. I want to implement some sort of an algorithm that could compute the four cardinal directions i.e. North East West South irrespective of the phone facing. For Example, If the phone is facing East and and the user is walking in the north direction then phone will still be showing the east direction , which is wrong the phone now should be show the north direction. In my idea i can get this to work if I could be able to transform the acceleration to the real world and then determining the direction of acceleration to show the real world coordinates.

Looking forward for your people's reply and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the user's heading reliably, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970).

I would use the GPS, as far as I know it can provide good velocity estimates. Good luck anyhow!

Comment: But the application is intended to use where the GPS is not present like indoor environments.

Comment: @jeniusj Please check the linked answer. It gives you examples what you actually can do in such situations.

Comment: Thanks Ali for your support, can we do it in an approximate way.......?? as you are saying that we cant do it in a reliable way.

Comment: @jeniusj What is it that you actually need? What would you like to do? If I know more perhaps I can come up with a workaround. Do you want to track the user's walk?

Comment: Ali here is my problem "For instance, if you are holding your smart phone in your hand and the phone is pointing towards East ( for example) but you walk towards North East or North, then the phone thinks you are actually moving in the East direction which is wrong because we are moving towards north.  My job is to develop an algorithm for detecting the direction of walk no matter which way the phone is pointing". And I have to do this where there is no GPS.

Comment: @jeniusj Yes, I could read that in your original question too. So you have to track walking. You will have trouble getting the direction of the walk regardless of the orientation of the phone. I would look into the indoor navigation papers I link to in my answer, maybe those offer you some workaround. Sorry I cannot help you any further with that, I have never done such applications.