# How to get only horizontal acceleration in accelerometer

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer, android-gps

Is it possible to get acceleration only in horizontal direction irrespective of the placement of the device.

I want to calculate acceleration of moving vehicle using android device. There may be cases where device is placed in any orientation. Is there any way by which i can calculate the acceleration of vehicle using accelerometer without calibrating each time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get accelerometers on earth coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701546/android-get-accelerometers-on-earth-coordinate-system)

Comment: And then, of course, the horizontal component would be the X and Y, which gives you west-east and south-north acceleration, respectively.