# Accelerometer direction ios

Tags: ios, iphone, math, uiaccelerometer

The formula for calculating acceleration from accelerometer values is sqrt(accelerometer.x^2 + accelerometer.y^2 + accelerometer.z^2).. But this does not give the direction in which the acceleration is happening. If there is a method that could even evaluate that if the acceleration was positive of negative?

I have a reference frame from which I am calculating all these values. All I need is the direction/positive or negative acceleration.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to say that the acceleration is positive/negative as it is just a vector. Maybe you want to ask whether the speed increases / decreases ? Or maybe you want to know about the acceleration in a particular direction ? (say vertical acceleration) ?

Comment: yes acceleration/decceleration in the direction of motion. Actually the GPS won't give the speed info. with the frequency of accelerometer updates (0.01). I need the acceleration in the vehicle's frame of reference, not the device frame of reference...

Comment: Acceleration is a vector: it has both magnitude and direction.  The components (ax, ay, az) represent the vector.  Your formula is for the magnitude of the vector; the normalized components give the direction.

Comment: Is this question related ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464847/transforming-accelerometers-data-from-devices-coordinates-to-real-world-coordi